# RecyclerView with table like layout and Sticky header -- Originally tried NestedScrollView with no success

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am building a daily schedule like for students. This schedule is in a fragment. I need a sticky header with seven day labels and then the items need to scroll underneath, all at once. In addition I need the entire view to scroll horizontally.

Currently I have a HorizontalScrollView, some nested LinearLayouts, and a NestedScrollView. There are 7 RecyclerViews that are children of the NestedScrollView, one for each day of the week. This is so that I can call `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` on each RecyclerView so they scroll together. Currently the result is that the NestedScrollView clips the RecyclerViews to 1 item and no scrolling is possible. If I remove the NestedScrollView The RecyclerViews all scroll individually which is not what I want.

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:elevation="4dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_schedule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                android:layout_width="74dp"
                android:layout_height="74dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                ...7 ImageViews representing days of week...

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/sunday_list"
                        android:layout_width="84dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:background="@color/accent_gold"/>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/monday_list"
                        android:layout_width="84dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        tools:background="@color/accent_gold"/>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/tuesday_list"
                        android:layout_width="84dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:background="@color/accent_gold"/>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/wednesday_list"
                        android:layout_width="84dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        tools:background="@color/accent_gold"/>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/thursday_list"
                        android:layout_width="84dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        tools:background="@color/accent_gold"/>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/friday_list"
                        android:layout_width="84dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        tools:background="@color/accent_gold"/>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/saturday_list"
                        android:layout_width="84dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        tools:background="@color/accent_gold"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The only thing of note in the fragment class is that I call `setNestedScrolledEnabled(false)` after populating and attaching all of the adapters.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this case is that I was thinking about the requirements too rigidly. I changed my layout to consists of a The header linear layout, a scrollview, and a horizontal recycler view, with each day being an item. In the adapter the item layout is simply a LinearLayout that I programmatically add the class views to(as there is a finite number of classes per day). Scrolling works in both directions. I will retitle the question so hopefully someone can find this working towards similar requirements.

**Fragment xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            android:layout_width="74dp"
            android:layout_height="74dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            ...Image Views Representing Days of Week...
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/day_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**RecyclerViewItem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="84dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/item_schedule_layout"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp">


</LinearLayout>
```

Then programmatically add views to the LinearLayout. My views for each class were complex so I created a custom view based on the layout I needed for each class and then was able to just define a new instance in a for loop and add it to the LinearLayout.